# customize button size in qualtrics

Tags: javascript, qualtrics

I was wondering if, through JavaScript, I can customize the question choice size on Qualtrics. Specifically, I want to narrow the width of the following choice. Is there a way to do that? I was told that CSS can help me with this, but it seems that function cannot be as specific as I wanted. All suggestion is welcomed!

Thanks

[Button example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J2VAR.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do something like this:

```
Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnload(function()
{
    var el = $(this.questionId).select('label.SingleAnswer').first();
    el.style.width = "50%";
    el.style.textAlign = "left";
});
```

EDIT: I've modified the answer above to address both the original question (width) and follow-up comment question (left align text).

Comment: It works! Thank you Gibbons! A follow-up question, is there a way to align this button to the left?

Answer (score 1):

Use [CSS](https://www.w3schools.com/css/). Less cumbersome than JS and you will also notice that your style changes won't have to wait for the page load to take effect.

Comment: The question you answered is over a year old and you can't target a specific button with CSS. At a minimum CSS will apply to the entire page.

Comment: Yes, you can target a specific button with CSS. Use the button's id.

Comment: It is generally a bad idea to use Qualtrics generated ids in css or code.